# Building a personal RF anechoic chamber in a large walk-in closet?

Tags: rf, radio, microwave, ham-radio

What would one need (besides many foam absorbers) to build an in-home small anechoic chamber for transmissions in the UHF to L-bands (specifically 500Mhz - 2 Ghz), and what resources would you point them towards?

Also does anything specific need to be under the foam absorbers?

For example, if a closet is 'unfinished' and only consists of wooden boards and some insulation between each board, could the absorbers go right on, what do you suggest?

Comment: What scattering parameters specs do you expect?  There will always be standing waves unless you have a lot of big lossy tetrahedral absorbers in a big walking closet.

Comment: You also need to be aware of (and shield from) any incoming RF interference, so grounded metal covering on all external walls (under the loss absorbers) would be needed.

Comment: things to keep in mind: for 500MHz your chamber needs to be relatively big in order to properly measure far field, >\$10\lambda\$ (6m) is a good guideline; shielding may be essential if you're going to use the chamber for receiver characterization, for instance; the absorbers are not trivial: they usually have a charcoal treatment and need to be big enough to work at lower frequencies.

Comment: This smacks of nonsense pseudo-science and no microwave understanding at all

Answer (score 1):

1. **Adjust your expectations.**  This is the most important step, so important that it occurs before we even begin building such a chamber.  You are not going to match any of the performance specs of a proper commissioned RF anechoic chamber with any sort of self-constructed one.  And even commissioned chambers require periodic retesting and adjustment to maintain their specs and keep their status as commissioned.  That said, you can certainly build something that will be far more electromagnetically quiet that anything one could otherwise achieve.  Just be (very) conservative in your expectations.  It is better to be pleasantly surprised than disappointed.
2. The outermost layer, which you would line the walls of the closet with, should be either a metal screen or just solid metal foil so as to form a **faraday cage** capable of shielding the closet from your highest frequency of interest.  A mesh with 1mm spacing (like what you see covering the window of microwave ovens) would be more than sufficient to attenuate as high as 2.4GHz.  This is simply to prevent outside RF from penetrating into the chamber, it won't be playing a role in the actual anechoic aspect, but it is important nonetheless.
3. The foam absorbers should be conductive, or painted with carbon black conductive paint, or ideally both.  The thing you want to search for is **radiation-absorbent material** or RAM.  You will either have to cut the pyramid shapes yourself or see if you can source some already made (though they will be expensive).  Conductive paint will do fairly well given the frequency range you want.  However, you will still have some reflections unless you manage to create an impedance/resistance gradient from tip to base of the cone that gradually matches the impedance of free space (377Ω).  Replicating this yourself is not really practical, but conductive paint alone will help a lot.  The idea is to be conductive, but still fairly resistive to dissipate as much of the RF energy as heat as possible.
4. **Have a fire extinguisher handy**.  Seriously.  Even modest RF power levels can sometimes create very concentrated heating of a small spot inside the chamber.  And the chamber is essentially designed to turn RF into heat.  The risk is low, but it is also easy and inexpensive to have a simple fire extinguisher handy, just in case.

But really, I think the time and effort you would spend for what will be fairly modest results just doesn't really add up.  You can purchase chambers the size of microwave ovens and larger.  There is even a walk-in RF anechoic chamber on ebay (at the time of writing) for sale.  Only $250,000!

But tabletop chambers can be had new for ~$10,000, and used for less.  And even the most questionable used chamber but of professional construction will likely give you far better results than anything you could build yourself.  And once you factor in the value of your own time that you would likely end up spending on such a project, it might even be cheaper.